# How can I connect USB 3 case jacks without a USB 3 motherboard header?

Tags: motherboard, usb-3, case

I just bought a new case, which has two USB 3.0 jacks on the front. The supplied internal cable for those jacks looks like this:

[image: USB 3.0 Dual Cable]

Unfortunately, my motherboard (an *[MSI H67MA-E35 (B3)](https://web.archive.org/web/20190505121901/https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/H67MAE35_B3.html)*) doesn't have a USB 3.0 header that I can connect the supplied internal cable to.

The motherboard is USB 3.0 capable, but it appears the only jacks are built in on the back I/O panel. What are my options to connect the new case's front USB 3.0 jacks?

Comment: What is the model of your motherboard?

Comment: It's an [MSI H67MA-E35 (B3)](https://us.msi.com/Motherboard/H67MAE35_B3.html#hero-overview)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have 3 options. The only way to get an internal connection that uses USB3.0 would be to buy a [USB3.0 pci card](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16815124123&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords-PC-_-pla-_-Add-On%20Cards-_-N82E16815124123&gclid=CPalk-6bicwCFY17fgoduMAN5g&gclsrc=aw.ds) that has a header slot on it.

[image: usb3 pci card]

If you want the cables to remain inside, (but use USB2.0), you will need this adapter.

[USB3 Header to USB2](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA67038T1454&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC-_-pla-_-Cables%20-%20Internal%20Power%20Cables-_-9SIA67038T1454&gclid=CJKkg96aicwCFZSCfgod-uANNA&gclsrc=aw.ds)

[image: usb3 head to usb2]

If you want to use the back of your current mobo and make the front ports "extensions" you will need this adapter.

[USB3 Header to USB3 male](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA6703JY7591&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleMKP-PC-_-pla-_-Cables%20-%20VGA%20%2F%20SVGA%20Cables-_-9SIA6703JY7591&gclid=CKuUwpSbicwCFRSPfgodoq8PPg&gclsrc=aw.ds)

[image: usb3 head to usb3 male adapter]

Comment: I've used an USB3.0 on my old USB2.0-only cheapo MB, and it works! The adapters are lkinda dodgy but work well.

Answer (score 5):

You can buy a PCI-E USB 3.0 controller with additional header like this one:

[image: Photo with header marked]

You'll have two extra USB 3.0 ports on the back and you'll be able to connect front ports to the controller. No unnecessarily occupied ports, at least four extra USB 3.0 ports.

Comment: That's what I figured I would need to get. Just out of curiosity, why do many of these internal cards have either a SATA or Molex power adapter? Do I need to supply power to them?

Comment: USB 3.0 [most commonly draws 10W when charging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_3.0#Charging) with "high power" charging drawing much more. Each PCIe card can draw a [max of 25W](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PCI_Express#Power). 4*10 > 25. Yes, you need power from PSU.